# FullCalendar - Adding Ajax elements to eventClick

Tags: javascript, ajax, razor, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am not sure if this can even be done. I have a custom system that creates a modal. The modal is generated by ajax.

there are two different ways I achieve this.

Normal CHTML page link:

```
@Ajax.ModalDialogActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Edit", "btn btn-warning btn-sm", new { id = item.QuoteId })
```

Pure Ajax:

```
'<li><a href="' + ControlerNameProject + "/Edit/" + row[0] + '" data-ajax-update="#SkEdit" data-ajax-success="openModalDialog(\'SkEdit\', \'Edit\')" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-failure="clearModalDialog(\'SkEdit\');alert(\'Ajax call failed\')" data-ajax-begin="prepareModalDialog(\'SkEdit\')" data-ajax="true"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square"></i>Quick Edit</a></li>';
```

I would like to add this feature to the eventClick for editing.

This is what I have tried, but this only opens a new page of Edit:

```
        eventDidMount: function (arg) {
            arg.el.onclick = function () {
                arg.data.ajax.attr('data-ajax-update', "#skEdit");
                arg.data.ajax.attr('data-ajax-success', "openModalDialog(\'SkEdit\', \'Edit\')");
                arg.data.ajax.attr('data-ajax-mode', "replace");
                arg.data.ajax.attr('data-ajax-method', "GET");
                arg.data.ajax.attr('data-ajax-begin', "prepareModalDialog(\'SkEdit\')")
                arg.data.ajax.attr('data-ajax', "true");
            }
        },
        eventClick: function (arg, element) {
            //window.location = "/CalendarManager/Edit/" + arg.event.id;
            location = "/CalendarManager/Edit/" + arg.event.extendedProps.eventId;

        },
        events: {
            url: '/CalendarManager/Findall',
            failure: function () {
                alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
            },
        },
```

I must be missing something or it just cannot be done..

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `location = ...` will cause the browser to navigate to a new URL. It has nothing to do with AJAX. Remove that.

Comment: Also, it makes no sense to add those attributes when the element is clicked...you need to add them _before_ it's clicked, so that they work already when the click happens.